# What distribution has the random variable of this exercise?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions

**The exercise says:** *There are 35 women and 45 men in a school. From this population are selected first 10 students and after a second selection, a final group of 6 students is determined. What is the probability that in this last group there are at least 5 women?*

**At first I would say that it is hypergeometric, but it happens that it is like there is a sample of 6 within another sample of 10, and there I do not know what to do. Could you help me?**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How would selecting the first sample and then sampling from it change the probabilities from just taking a sample of six at the first draw?

If you think there must be a difference, let's perform a little thought experiment; in fact let's conduct a series of related experiments. We have a deep bowl with 35 red and 45 green balls (otherwise identical) in it. Assume they're about the size of marbles (roughly a centimeter or so in diameter), so we can hold a dozen or more at one time.

Before each experiment, we mix the balls around thoroughly (after replacing any balls drawn on a previous experiment).

Experiment 1: We turn out the lights and draw out 10 balls and place them into a bag, from which we then draw six and (after turning on the lights again) look at them. (This is analogous to your original problem)

Experiment 2: We reach in and pull out 10 balls with one hand; without looking, we drop four of them back in, leaving six in hand.

Experiment 3: We reach in and grab 10 balls with one hand but leave our hand in the urn; we let four fall out and we take our hand out with the remaining six.

Experiment 4: We reach in to take some balls; our hand touches 10 of the balls, of which we take six.

Experiment 5: We reach in and stir the balls around a bit more -- we touch dozens of balls, we don't know how many, and pull out six.

Experiment 6: We reach in and draw out six balls.

Can you suggest which pair of consecutive experiments will have a different distribution for the six balls (assuming they're already well-mixed each time)? (And if so, why would the distributions of ball colors change there?)

---

If it's still not convincing that it makes no difference, consider a simpler case (one which is easy to enumerate all the possibilities for):

(**A**) There are 2 red and 3 white balls. Draw 3. Then from that pool of 3 draw 2. What's the probability they're both red?

... compare that with ...

(**B**) There are 2 red and 3 white balls. Draw 2. What's the probability they're both red?

Note that for (A) if you label the 5 balls A, B, C, D, E, the possible pools of 3 are (ignoring order):

```
ABC --> RRW
ABD --> RRW
ABE --> RRW
ACD --> RWW
ACE --> RWW
ADE --> RWW
BCD --> RWW
BCE --> RWW
BDE --> RWW
CDE --> WWW
```

of which the first three have two red. In those 3/10 cases, the chance of two reds in the second round is .... ?

Comment: In fact, no, I can not. So what matters is the latest sample?

Comment: I've added some more stuff for you to consider.

Comment: I can not suggest which pair of consecutive experiments will have a different distribution for the six balls. That's what I meant.

Comment: @emi yes, I understood; you can't do so because there is *actually* no difference in the probabilities at any point. It's a thought experiment designed to make that plain. The point of breaking it up like that is that 1 and 6 might look potentially different but if you break it up into a sequence of very similar experiments it's easy to see that it *can't* make a difference, because otherwise there'd be a difference in probability at at least one of those points on the progression from 1 to 6. My added explanation was just to accompany that intuition with a simple calculation ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... which shows that they're the same (and if you think about that calculation carefully, you'll see there's a cancellation that makes it clear why that must always be so)